# Solve Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) in Python

Tags: python, linear-algebra, idl, svd, idl-programming-language

I amtrying to translate an IDL program to Python. I have to solve the outcome from `SVD` which I achieve in the following way

```
from scipy.linalg import svd
A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [4,4,5]

u,w,v = svd(A)
```

And this works fine and is translated nicely from IDL. The next step is IN IDL(!)

```
x = svsol(u,w,v,b)
```

The `u` in python and IDL are almost the same (and for the other matrix's as well). The only difference is the dimensions, where IDL's matrix's is larger, but has a lot of zeros. It looks like Python's matrix's are more compressed in that sence.

Does anyone know something similarly for Python.

If anyone needs it, here is the manual for [`svsol`](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/SVSOL.html).

Comment: Can't you just use: [`scipy.linalg.solve(A,b)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html)?

Comment: No, I am looking for something similar to `svsol` in IDL. The method I am following has to use this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `SVDC` and `SVSOL` in IDL you solve a linear least squares problem by SVD decomposition. This is done in `numpy` by the `numpy.linalg.lstsq` function. (No need to compute first the SVD decomposition and then back solve.)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> b = np.array([4,4])
>>> x, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
>>> x
array([-2.,  0.,  2.])
>>> np.dot(A,x)
array([ 4.,  4.])
```

Please note that the length of `b` has to be the same as the number of rows of `A`, so your example is wrong. Just to make shure that I'm correctly interpreting the IDL semantics, here is the example in the `svsol` [reference manual](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/SVSOL.html):

```
>>> A = np.array(
... [[1.0, 2.0, -1.0, 2.5],
...  [1.5, 3.3, -0.5, 2.0],
...  [3.1, 0.7,  2.2, 0.0],
...  [0.0, 0.3, -2.0, 5.3],
...  [2.1, 1.0,  4.3, 2.2],
...  [0.0, 5.5,  3.8, 0.2]])
>>> B = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 5.3, -2.0, 6.3, 3.8])
>>> x, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A,B)
>>> print x
[ 1.00095058  0.00881193  0.98417587 -0.01009547]
```

Comment: That seems to work really great. I think I'll just use the least square method then. Just of curiosity, can you tell my the advantages of SVD (if there is any) over `lstsq`.
Thank you really much for your help; it is very preciated!

Comment: @DanielThaagaardAndreasen internally `np.linalg.lstsq` calls LAPACK [`dgelsd`](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgelsd.f) which in turns is SVD based, so conceptually there are no differences. This said usually `dgelsd` turns out to be faster than full SVD and subsequent back solve. For more info have a a look at the LAPACK [user guide](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node27.html)